# xamDataGrid filter record styling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I'm trying to change the background color of the filter record in a xamDataGrid.

I've tried `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}, AddRowBackground}" Color="Red"/>` as suggested on the Infragistics forums, and

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordPresenter}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsFilterRecord}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="#363636" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but neither of them worked, my filter row is still white.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordCellArea}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The background color comes from a border within the template that uses the AddRowBackground resource.  This resource can be set with the following

`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid}, AddRowBackground}" Color="#363636"/>`

DataPresenterBrushKeys Class: 
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v11.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataPresenterBrushKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late but I've encountered the same issue.
What I've found is that I was setting DataRecordCellArea Background which overlaped the AddRowBackground.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:DataRecordCellArea}">      
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridBackgroundBrush}" />
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type igDp:XamDataGrid}, AddRowBackground}" Color="Red"/>
```

**To fix that I've commented out the DataRecordCellArea background**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:DataRecordCellArea}">      
      <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridBackgroundBrush}" />-->
<!-- other stters -->
    </Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type igDp:XamDataGrid}, AddRowBackground}" Color="Red"/>
```

And now the filter row background is red